# ubuntu 14.04 wont connect to ethernet - trying manual question

Tags: 14.04, server, dns, ethernet, documentation

I'm very new to linux - I'm on my chromebook now trying to look up answers.

So I can't connect my linux run pc to my Ethernet (I know it's working as my chromebook can connect to it) so I'm now trying to do it manually but I don't know how to find my DNS server to finish the manual set up... I'm assuming I have to look it up on the chromebook as there is no internet on my pc. But I can't seem to get the info if it is even applicable to my pc... any suggestions?

Thank you, Winter

I am not able to post so I'm trying this to list what I've tried all the normal things to get it to auto-connect. Now I'm trying to do manual connect. I put in IP address, Mask address, and Gateway address. I do not know my DNS server though.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please avoid using slang or textual short-cuts - not everyone understands it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a home LAN, then your immediate upstream DNS service is likely provided by your router, in which case the DNS server IP is usually the same as the gateway IP.

If on the other hand you have a direct modem (PPP) connection to your ISP, they likely provided you with the IP(s) of their own DNS server(s) that you can use.

In either case, you could instead use one of a number of publicly available DNS services such as

GOOGLE

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

OpenDNS

```
208.67.222.222
208.67.220.220
```